# Group By With Special Condition To Select Row

Tags: sql, oracle

My Table

```
Id | Add  | Check | RESULT | Seq
__________________________________________
1  | 2    | 1     | 1      | 10
1  | 2    | 1     | 2      | 20
2  | 3    | 4     | 4      | 30
2  | 3    | 4     | 4      | 40
3  | 5    | 2     | 2      | 50
4  | 2    | 6     | 2      | 60
```

I Want This Result.

```
Id | Add  | Check | RESULT | Seq
__________________________________________
1  | 2    | 1     | 2      | 20
2  | 3    | 4     | 4      | 30
3  | 5    | 2     | 2      | 50
4  | 2    | 6     | 2      | 60
```

I Want Query like this

```
Select 
(if add==result then return row else return row with min(seq) ) 
From MyTable 
Group by Id.
```

Please Help Me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when add = result then 1 else 2 end),
                                         seq
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you can have duplicate rows where `add = result`, then this can be tweaked to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

This query will give you the results you want. It looks for rows where `Add = Result`, or where `Seq` is the minimum value for that `Add` value, but only where no row matching the first condition exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable m1
WHERE "Add" = "RESULT"
   OR "Seq" = (SELECT MIN("Seq") FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2."Add" = m1."Add")
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable m3 WHERE m3."Add" = m1."Add" AND m3."Add" = m3."RESULT")
```

Output:

```
Id  Add     Check   RESULT  Seq
1   2       1       2       20
2   3       4       4       30
3   5       2       2       50
4   2       6       2       60
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=620cfcedcb793b1ad999c57738589fd4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical functions as following:

```
SELECT ID, ADD, CHECK, RESULT,
       CASE WHEN ADD = RESULT THEN SEQ ELSE MIN_SEQ END AS SEQ 
 FROM
   (SELECT ID, ADD, CHECK, RESULT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CASE WHEN ADD = RESULT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RESULT_RN,
           SEQ, MIN(SEQ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) MIN_SEQ
      FROM YOUR_TABLE)
WHERE RESULT_RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!